# What form of alias analysis does Visual C++ use?

Tags: optimization, visual-c++, compiler-construction, static-analysis

I'm trying to figure out what form of **alias analysis** is used in Visual C++. It's also known as pointer analysis, mod-ref analysis, points-to analysis or side-effect analysis, and is pretty close to escape analysis or shape analysis (should you have seen those terms bandied about).

If anyone knows where MSDN discusses this sort of thing, I can probably find my way from there. *(I tried searching, but MSDN seems to be impenetrable if you don't spend much time there.)*

Comment: MSDN is tough.  It's better to use Google with site:msdn.com than to use MSDN search itself.

Comment: I would assume they would bring as much weaponry to bear as possible, since aliased results disables lots of optimizations.  So I would't expect the answer to be simple.  Even if they used a "points-to" analysis, there's lots of variations: flow-sensitive/insensitive, context-sensitive or not, feild-sensitive or not, intra procedural, interprocedure, cross compilation units, ...
What's behind the question?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: That's exactly what I'm trying to figure out. Is it flow-, context-, field-, object-, etc sensitive? What's behind it: Am doing my literature review for my phd thesis, and I realized I know the answer (or how to find the answer) for gcc, LLVM, and a few other compilers, but I couldn't find it for Visual C++.

Comment: TBH, you'd probably get better results from the MSDN VC++ developer blogs than MSDN itself for this sort of thing

Answer (score 2):

Going purely by MSDN documentation:

"Assume No aliasing" ([**/Oa**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984741%28VS.71%29.aspx)) and related options have been removed in [**Visual Studio 2008**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe%28VS.90%29.aspx).

__declspec([**restrict**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bcxafdh.aspx)) and __declspec([**noalias**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k649tyc7.aspx)) have been added (2003 or earlier, see also [**Optimization best practices**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235601.aspx))

From that *I* would conclude that the compiler/optimizer by default assumes aliasing under the C++ rules (roughly, pointers of the same type may point to the same memory). This seems a sensible move in avoiding errors due to a global overly agressive /Oa option.

I would further assume that link-time code generation increases the scope in which non-aliasing can be detected.

---

The best non-MSDN reference I could find is this: [**VC++ team blog**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/09/17/phoenix-time-reporting-mechanisms.aspx). However, this just indicates that the compiler *does spend some time* on alias analysis. Maybe the [**Channel9**](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Andy-Ayers-Understanding-the-Phoenix-Compiler-Framework) video linked gives some insight.

(Some people had luck with asking for more info in the VC++ comments. Hint hint...)

---

[**edit**] I don't know if Phoenix ended up in VS2010, the video talks about aliasing 6:00, but nothing spectacular.